# How to edit a file over ssh in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a BASH script that will perform the following

1. SSH to remote machine
2. move to a directory
3. open a file for editing
4. continue with other commands once user has edited the file

I know that steps 1 and 2 can be achieved by doing `ssh server "cmds"` but that won't work for 3, since it doesn't display what is happening.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to use a `gui` editor then add the `-X` flag/option when invoking ssh.

Comment: it will be easier if you use FileZilla

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work for you?:

```
ssh -t user@server "cd /folder/; nano somefile; execute_a_command_once_nano_is_closed"
```

`nano` or `joe` or `vi` or `vim` are text editors that work via the console, and you can interact wit them

If you can or want to automate the edits, you can use `sed` or `awk` to do the edits/manipulation of the files, and not use interactive editor at all.

Comment: The OP will probably need the `-t` option to force a pseudo-terminal to be allocated, as the editor will expect one.

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
ssh root@<your_server> "sed -i 's/cat/dog/g' /tmp/test_file"
```

from:
cat /tmp/test_file
#This is a test file will be edited
cat

to:
cat /tmp/test_file
#This is a test file will be edited
dog

note: I suggest setup ssh passwordless so you wont be typing password ever you execute the ssh command or might want to look in to ansible